# Display of valgrind results in Jenkins does not look correct

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, valgrind

I am running multiple unit tests for a software on different target platforms during a Jenkins build. This includes running Valgrind using the memcheck tool.

I use the [Valgrind plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/valgrind/) plugin, and use the `publishValgrind` method in the post conditions like so:

```
publishValgrind failBuildOnInvalidReports: true, failBuildOnMissingReports: false, failThresholdDefinitelyLost: '0', failThresholdInvalidReadWrite: '0', failThresholdTotal: '0', pattern: '**/*.memcheck', publishResultsForAbortedBuilds: false, publishResultsForFailedBuilds: true, unstableThresholdDefinitelyLost: '0', unstableThresholdInvalidReadWrite: '0', unstableThresholdTotal: '0', sourceSubstitutionPaths: ''
```

The results from this are displayed like so (The redacted data are paths to processes):

[image: Valgrind results with some company data redacted]

This output does not match what the plugin describes, as all the results that are displayed contain suppressed errors, and then there are two that contain possible memory leaks. This is not really helpful as is, as it contains a lot of entries, and doesn't really highlight the possible issues.

I would like the displayed data to be as described in the screenshots of the plugin site, but I cannot find anything wrong with the configuration, or the output `memcheck` files.

I have checked all the valgrind plugin output, and it contains nothing unusual except for:

```
423 09:39:46  [Valgrind] Analysing valgrind results

424 09:39:46  [Valgrind] '/builddir/build/BUILD/valgrind-3.15.0/coregrind/m_replacemalloc/vg_replace_malloc.c' does not exist, source code won't be available

425 09:39:46  [Valgrind] '/builddir/build/BUILD/valgrind-3.17.0/coregrind/m_replacemalloc/vg_replace_malloc.c' does not exist, source code won't be available
```

I have checked the *.memcheck files, and they seem to contain only expected stuff.

Comment: Why do you have 2 Valgrind versions in the log? The messages don't come from Valgrind.